# Basis of vector space and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-independence

if a set of n vectors is spanning a n dimensional vector space, then does this means that vectors are linearly independent ?

The doubt is coming from the statement which says- " **If Dim V =n and set $S = \{α_1, α_2.....,α_n\}$ spans
V then S is a basis of V** ".

Comment: Yes, if they weren't linearly independent, you could express one by linear combination of the $n-1$ others, so the $n-1$ others span the spame space, so the space is at most $n-1$-dimensional.